# How to write Junit test for a method with "this" inside

Tags: java, junit

I have the following method:

```
public class Store {

   @Autowired 
   private List<Products> products;

   public Products find(final String id) {
        for (final Products product : this.products) {
            if (product.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                return product;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How to write Junit for this method?
If i write like this then NullPointerException occurs.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:beans.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class StoreTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Autowired
    private List<Products> products;

    @Test
    public void find() {
        Store store = new Store();
        Products product = new Products();
        product = store.find("1");
        final String result = product.getName();
        Assert.assertEquals("it should be equal", "Milk", result);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `products` initialized? Can you send the snippet when `products` is declared and initialized with a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the Products object or List of Products to the store so it makes sense that find is returning null.

What you can do is add the product to the store then check if the result of product is null and if so assert that something has gone wrong. You can also check if the Products you added is the Products you're finding.

```java
@Test
public void find() {
    final Store store = new Store();

    final List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

    final Products product1 = new Products("Cucumber", "The best cucmber", 500, "1");
    final Products product2 = new Products("Cherry", "The best Cherry", 1000, "2");
    Products product = new Products();

    products.add(product1);
    products.add(product2);

    Products found = store.find("1");

    Assert.assertNotNull(product); // check if result is null

    Assert.assertEquals(product, found); // check if what you added is your result
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here with a much better description then I can provide with the character limitation; https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your class `Store` it is possible to set a value for `this.products`. Maybe there is a setter: `setProducts(List<Product> products)`. You need to set the field to a correct value for your test case. This is called test preparation.

In general you should avoid using `@Autowired` on fields and use constructor based injection instead. This makes it more obvious that your Store object requires a dependency to work and it is easy to provide a mock in your testcase:

```
public class Store {
    private List<Products> products;

    @Autowired
    public Store(List<Products> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    ...
}
```

-

```
@Test
public void find() {
    final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    final Product product1 = new Product("Cucumber", "The best cucmber", 500, "1");
    final Product product2 = new Product("Cherry", "The best Cherry", 1000, "2");
    products.add(product1);
    products.add(product2);
    // here you are inserting your mocked products list into your object under test, to contain the expected results
    final Store store = new Store(products); 

    Products found = store.find("1");

    Assert.assertNotNull(product); // check if result is null

    Assert.assertEquals(product, found); // check if what you added is your result
}
```

In general you should improve your code to be null-safe. Instead of throwing a NullPointerException. your code productive code should check if the field is null before and return a valid, empty result in this case.

```
public Products find(final String id) {
    if (this.product != null) {
        for (final Products product : this.products) {
            if (product.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                return product;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my code. Could you please take a look? I still don't know how to get an object of the Store class which is connected with injected products. So i could use it with find method in test.

Comment: @VladStarostenko: I updated my answer to cover your case with the annotation.